# Right place to add a new comment on lazy loading screen

Tags: mobile, tables, comments, lazy-loading

Consider a mobile app screen with many comments, which are ordered by created date (oldest first).

Comments are lazily loaded, page size = `10`.

Now please consider the following use case:

1. The user enters the screen with `100` comments.
2. As soon as he enters, the app loads `10` oldest comments.
3. The user leaves a new comment without scrolling down.

**Question: where should the app place this new comment?**

Should it load all the comments and append the new comment to the end of the array? Or should it place the new comment at the top of the array? Both cases seems bad to me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunate set of constraints, but if you have these constraints, you should most accurately represent the user's comments in relationship to the comments it will live "next to" in chronological order. Don't misrepresent the comment placement.

Keeping page size=10 in mind, if you have 100 comments and this is comment 101, the view should change from 1-10 to represent the new comment posted...hence 91-101. You could or should also scroll-to the comment that was now posted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't insist on these constraints, but it seems logical to me to have comments ordered be date created. And lazy loading is essential these days.